# "RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?id=$1" posts "index" instead entered text

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I do it by typing `/?id=some_text` in url then index.php script works as it shuld but if I do `/some_text` then index.php always receives id to have value "index".

At first I had `RewriteRule ^([^/]+) ?id=$1` but that returned "Internal Server Error" instead web page, then I changed it to RewriteRule ^([a-z]+) index.php?id=$1 and I stoped reciving error page but script started to receive "index" as value no matter what i typed in

This rule worked on local machine using MAMP, but when I uploaded it on server it stoped working.

.htaccess file for this folder only contains this rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) ?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was probably trying to recurse through index.php since it appears to match the rule.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !index
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The RewriteCond is to ensure it doesn't apply the rule to the results of itself.  And [L] is to make sure it doesn't try applying any other rule.